# Command line: undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby

I got the following code:

```
require 'base64'

def Decrypt(rsaCipher, encryptedValue)
  print base64.decode64(encryptedValue)
end

Decrypt("a", "b")
```

I get the error message `in 'Decrypt': undefined local variable or method 'base64' for main:Object (NameError)'`. What am I doing wrong? Why isn't Ruby detecting the `base64` library even though I included it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `Base64` but not `base64`.................................**[See the doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html)**.

Comment: That figures. Thanks .. *runs for cover*